# Drop down using knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Currently I'm working on making a pretty basic timesheet.
So what i currently have is a button to hit add employee and it generates a week for them. What i would  like to have happen is where the employee name input be a drop down instead but im not sure how to proceed, heres what i have so far
a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/grahamwalsh/1p3nnkyg/

HTML

```
<div class='timesheet'> 

<form action='/someServerSideHandler'>
    <p>You have asked for <span data-bind='text: employees().length'>&nbsp;</span> employee(s)</p>
    <table data-bind='visible: employees().length > 0'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
                <th>Saturday</th>
                <th>Sunday</th>
                <th />
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind='foreach: employees'>
            <tr>
                <td><input class='required' data-bind='value: name, uniqueName: true' /></td>
                <td><input class='required number' data-bind='value: hours, uniqueName: true' /></td>
```

Delete

```
    <button data-bind='click: addEmployee'>Add Employee</button>
    <button data-bind='enable: employees().length > 0' type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Knockout

```
var EmployeeModel = function(employees) {
var self = this;
self.employees = ko.observableArray(employees);

self.addEmployee = function() {
    self.employees.push({
        Name: "",
        Monday: "",
        Tuesday:"",
        Wednesday:"",
        Thursday:"",
        Friday:"",
        Saturday:"",
        Sunday:""
    });
};

self.removeEmployee = function(employee) {
    self.employees.remove(employee);
};

self.save = function(form) {
    alert("Could now transmit to server: " + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.employees));

};
};

var viewModel = new EmployeeModel([
 ]);
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

 $("form").validate({ submitHandler: viewModel.save });


body { font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; }

 .timesheet { padding: 1em; background-color: #EEEEDD; border: 1px solid #CCC; max-width: 655px; }
 .timesheet input { font-family: Arial; }
 .timesheet b { font-weight: bold; }
 .timesheet p { margin-top: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; }
 .timesheet select[multiple] { width: 100%; height: 8em; }
 .timesheet h2 { margin-top: 0.4em; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;     }

.timesheet table, .liveExample td, .liveExample th { padding: 0.2em; border-width: 0; }
.timesheet td input { width: 13em; }
 tr { vertical-align: top; }
 .timesheet input.error { border: 1px solid red; background-color: #FDC; }
 .timesheet label.error { display: block; color: Red; font-size: 0.8em; } 
 .timesheet th { font-weight: bold; }

  li { list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 20px; }
```

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/1p3nnkyg/6/ . cheers

Comment: @Liz as an aside - I just noticed that you haven't accepted any answers to your questions so far. [It would be great if you could do so](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so that your questions don't show up as "unanswered" any more; it makes it easier for others to distinguish who still needs help, and who doesn't. Thank you!

Comment: hi sorry i will certainly do so, how do i accept them?

Comment: Thanks! Click the small check mark under the score of the answer you wish to accept. [Here is a screenshot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Also, when you write comments, you can include someones name with an @-sign, e.g. @janfoeh. That person then gets a notification that you've replied to them — they might otherwise miss your response. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want your users to choose one or more people from a list of employees. Your approach had a couple of problems, which I am trying to correct along the way.

You named your viewmodel `EmployeeModel`, but you also had basically another ad-hoc data model for employees:

```
self.employees.push({
    Name: "",
    Monday: "",
    Tuesday:"",
    Wednesday:"",
    Thursday:"",
    Friday:"",
    Saturday:"",
    Sunday:""
});
```

This by the way won't work, because you forgot to make the properties observables. If you bind `Name` to an input field value, such as `<input data-bind="value: Name">`, it will only set the input to the initial content of `Name` once. After that, nothing will happen anymore, no matter if you change either the observable `Name` or the `<input>` value.

So let's rename your viewmodel to `ViewModel` and create a dedicated data model for `Employee`:

```
var Employee = function Employee(name) {
    this.name      = ko.observable(name);
    this.monday    = ko.observable();
    this.tuesday   = ko.observable();
    this.wednesday = ko.observable();
    this.thursday  = ko.observable();
    this.friday    = ko.observable();
    this.saturday  = ko.observable();
    this.sunday    = ko.observable();
};
```

For the purposes of this demo, I'll feed them directly into the viewmodel:

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel([
    new Employee('Jane'),
    new Employee('John'),
    new Employee('Alice'),
    new Employee('Bob')
]);
```

We basically have two lists —

1. a list of employees the user can choose from, and
2. those employees the user has selected

so we need two observableArrays:

```
var ViewModel = function ViewModel(employees) {
    this.availableEmployees = ko.observableArray(employees);
    this.selectedEmployees  = ko.observableArray([]);
};
```

I would change the user interface and make the user select the employee first:

[image]

This way, we can use a dynamic select that only contains the employees that haven't been added yet, allowing us to prevent an employee from being added twice.

This is our `<select>`:

```
<!-- ko if: availableEmployees().length > 0 -->
    <select data-bind="value: employeeToBeAdded,
                       options: availableEmployees,
                       optionsText: 'name'">
    </select>
    <button data-bind='click: addEmployee'>Add Employee</button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

We create the options from all `availableEmployees`, and use the `name` property of each `Employee` for the option label text. If none are available, we hide everything.

`employeeToBeAdded` is another observable, holding the employee currently selected in the `<select>` that will be added when "Add Employee" is clicked.

When that happens, we get the selected employee from the list, add it to `selectedEmployees` and remove it from `availableEmployees`. For `removeEmployee`, we do the reverse:

```
var ViewModel = function ViewModel(employees) {
    var self = this;

    this.availableEmployees = ko.observableArray(employees);
    this.selectedEmployees  = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.employeeToBeAdded  = ko.observable();

    this.addEmployee = function addEmployee() {
        var employee = self.employeeToBeAdded();
        self.employeeToBeAdded(null);
        self.selectedEmployees.push( employee );
        self.availableEmployees.remove( employee );        
    };

    this.removeEmployee = function removeEmployee(employee) {
        self.availableEmployees.push(employee);
        self.selectedEmployees.remove(employee);
    };
};
```

Here is the full, runnable example:

```js
var Employee = function Employee(name) {
    this.name      = ko.observable(name);
    this.monday    = ko.observable();
    this.tuesday   = ko.observable();
    this.wednesday = ko.observable();
    this.thursday  = ko.observable();
    this.friday    = ko.observable();
    this.saturday  = ko.observable();
    this.sunday    = ko.observable();
};

var ViewModel = function ViewModel(employees) {
    var self = this;
    
    this.availableEmployees = ko.observableArray(employees);
    this.selectedEmployees  = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.employeeToBeAdded  = ko.observable();
    
    this.addEmployee = function() {
        var employee = self.employeeToBeAdded();
        self.employeeToBeAdded(null);
        self.selectedEmployees.push(employee);
        self.availableEmployees.remove(employee);        
    };
 
    self.removeEmployee = function(employee) {
        self.availableEmployees.push(employee);
        self.selectedEmployees.remove(employee);
    };
 
    self.save = function(form) {
        alert("Could now transmit to server: " + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.employees));
       
    };
};
 
var viewModel = new ViewModel([
    new Employee('Jane'),
    new Employee('John'),
    new Employee('Alice'),
    new Employee('Bob')
]);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; }

.timesheet { padding: 1em; background-color: #EEEEDD; border: 1px solid #CCC; max-width: 655px; }
.timesheet input { font-family: Arial; }
.timesheet b { font-weight: bold; }
.timesheet p { margin-top: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; }
.timesheet select[multiple] { width: 100%; height: 8em; }
.timesheet h2 { margin-top: 0.4em; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em; }

.timesheet table, .liveExample td, .liveExample th { padding: 0.2em; border-width: 0; }
.timesheet td input { width: 5em; }
tr { vertical-align: top; }
.timesheet input.error { border: 1px solid red; background-color: #FDC; }
.timesheet label.error { display: block; color: Red; font-size: 0.8em; } 
.timesheet th { font-weight: bold; }

li { list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 20px; }

.debugging-output { padding: 2rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='timesheet'> 
    
    <form action='/someServerSideHandler'>
        <p>You have asked for <span data-bind='text: selectedEmployees().length'>&nbsp;</span> employee(s)</p>
        <table data-bind='visible: selectedEmployees().length > 0'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Monday</th>
                    <th>Tuesday</th>
                    <th>Wednesday</th>
                    <th>Thursday</th>
                    <th>Friday</th>
                    <th>Saturday</th>
                    <th>Sunday</th>
                    <th />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind='foreach: selectedEmployees'>
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                    <td><input class='required number' data-bind='value: monday, uniqueName: true' /></td>
                    <td><input class='required number' data-bind='value: tuesday, uniqueName: true' /></td>
                    <td><input class='required number' data-bind='value: wednesday, uniqueName: true' /></td>
                    <td><input class='required number' data-bind='value: thursday, uniqueName: true' /></td>
                    <td><input class='required number' data-bind='value: friday, uniqueName: true' /></td>
                    <td><input class='required number' data-bind='value: saturday, uniqueName: true' /></td>
                    <td><input class='required number' data-bind='value: sunday, uniqueName: true' /></td>
                    <td><button data-bind='click: $parent.removeEmployee'>Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     
        <!-- ko if: availableEmployees().length > 0 -->
            <select data-bind="value: employeeToBeAdded, options: availableEmployees, optionsText: 'name'"></select>
            <button data-bind='click: addEmployee'>Add Employee</button>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <button data-bind='enable: selectedEmployees().length > 0' type='submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
    
</div>

<ul class="debugging-output" data-bind="foreach: selectedEmployees">
  <li data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></li>
</ul>
```